# How do I use systemd to replace cron jobs meant to run every five minutes?

Tags: cron, systemd, periodic-task

We have an embedded target environment (separate from out host build environment) in which `systemd` is running but not `cron`.

We also have a script which, under most systems, I would simply create a `cron` entry to run it every five minutes.

Now I know how to create a *service* under `systemd` but this script is a one-shot that exits after it's done its work. What I'd like to do is have it run immediately on boot (after the `syslog.target`, of course) then every five minutes thereafter.

After reading up on `systemd` timers, I created the following service file is `/lib/systemd/system/xyzzy.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=XYZZY
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xyzzy.dash
```

and equivalent `/lib/systemd/system/xyzzy.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=XYZZY scheduler

[Timer]
OnBootSec=0min
OnUnitActiveSec=5min

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Unfortunately, when booting the target, the timer does not appear to start since the output of `systemctl list-timers --all` does not include it. Starting the timer unit manually seems to work okay but this is something that should be run automatically with user intervention.

I would have thought the `WantedBy` would ensure the timer unit was installed and running and would therefore start the service periodically. However, I've noticed that the `multi-user.target.wants` directory does not actually have a symbolic link for the timer.

How is this done in `systemd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer is not active until you actually enable it:

```
systemctl enable xyzzy.timer
```

If you want to see how it works before rebooting, you can also start it:

```
systemctl start xyzzy.timer
```

In terms of doing that for a *separate* target environment where you aren't necessarily able to easily run arbitrary commands at boot time (but do presumably control the file system content), you can simply create the same symbolic links (in your development area) that the `enable` command would do.

For example (assuming `SYSROOT` identifies the root directory of the target file system):

```
ln -s ${SYSROOT}/lib/systemd/system/xyzzy.timer
      ${SYSROOT}/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/xyzzy.timer
```

This will effectively put the timer unit into an enabled state for the `multi-user.target`, so `systemd` will start it with that target.

---

Also, normally your custom files would be stored in `/etc/systemd/system/`. The equivalent `lib` directory is intended to host  `systemd` files installed by packages or the OS.

If it's important that your cron job run *precisely* every 5 minutes, you should check the accuracy because [systemd's monotonic timers can slip over time](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4083)

Comment: That's rather annoying. Given that the whole purpose of `systemd` is to handle startup activities, we need to either manually start it up or use some *other* boot-time facility to do so? Perhaps I didn't make it obvious in the question but the target environment is separate to development so it's not just a simple matter of running that on my dev box since that won't affect the target. What I need to do is to ensure the target, after booting, does this without intervention. It's a little disappointing that `systemd` doesn't seem to do this itself based on the copious unit files.

Comment: As seen in the system docs, the function of the `enable` subcommand is to run the commands in the `[Install]` section of a Unit file. Usually this for setting a unit to run automatically at boot. Once a unit is enabled, it will start on *every* boot, no manual intervention required.

Comment: Mark, I'm not sure I was clear. It seems to me `systemd` should be perfectly capable of doing this itself with a stanza in the unit file. Given it *loads* these unit files from a known location at boot time, an option like this would be invaluable for target systems rather than relying on some other method. It appears there's no way to get `systemd` to do this other than creating the symbolic links in the target filesystem, similar to what `enable` does. I wasn't denigrating your answer, just commenting that it appears to be a shortcoming.

Comment: BTW, I *have* actually solved it using the symbolic link creation method but it's a bit of a kludge.

Comment: @paxdiablo using symlinks to enable/disable services is also how SysVinit and Upstart works. The design plays well with scripting and automation, because it's easy to script creating or removing a symlink. It's much harder to script opening up a configuration file, correctly parsing it, and modifying the right text correctly.  If `systemd` also supported enabling services in the Unit files then unless they did away with the script-friendly symlinks, something would have to reconcile the state configured in the file with the symlinks.

Comment: Mark, made some changes to add the separate dev/deploy situation, hope you don't mind [ you *shouldn't* since I also accepted the answer :-) ] Thanks for your help.